# How do I generate authenticated S3 urls using IAM roles?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

When I had my hard-coded access key and secret key present, I was able to generate authenticated urls for users to view private files on S3. This was done with the following code:

```
import hmac
import sha
import urllib
import time

filename = "".join([s3_url_prefix, filename])
expiry = str(int(time.time()) + 3600)
h = hmac.new(
    current_app.config.get("S3_SECRET_KEY", None),
    "".join(["GET\n\n\n", expiry, "\n", filename]),
    sha
)
signature = urllib.quote_plus(base64.encodestring(h.digest()).strip())
return "".join([
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com",
    filename,
    "?AWSAccessKeyId=",
    current_app.config.get("S3_ACCESS_KEY", None),
    "&Expires=",
    expiry,
    "&Signature=",
    signature
])
```

Which gave me something to the effect of https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/path_to_file?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxx&Expires=5555555555&Signature=eBFeN32eBb2MwxKk4nhGR1UPhk%3D. Unfortunately, I am unable to store keys in config files for security reasons. For this reason, I switched over to IAM roles. Now, I get my keys using:

```
_iam = boto.connect_iam()

S3_ACCESS_KEY = _iam.access_key
S3_SECRET_KEY = _iam.secret_key
```

However, this gives me the error "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.". From my research, I understand that this is because my IAM keys aren't the actual keys, but instead used with a token. My question therefore, is twofold:

1. How do I get the token programatically? It doesn't seem that there is a simple iam property I can use.
2. How do I send the token in the signature? I believe my signature should end up looking something like "".join(["GET\n\n\n", expiry, "\n", token, filename]), but I can't figure out what format to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a change to the `generate_url` method in https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/99e14f3df039997f54a5377cb6aecc83f22c2670 (June 2012) that made it possible to sign a URL using session credentials.  That means you would need to be using a boto version 2.6.0 or later.  If you are, you should be able to just do this:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
url = s3.generate_url(expires_in=3600, method='GET', bucket='<bucket_name>', key='<key_name>')
```

What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, that definitely did it. All of the forms I read said that wouldn't work, but they were out of date. For anyone who is interested, you can still make this work using my above method, and adding the token in the query string as "x-amz-security-token".